# How to create reusable Modal in react native

Tags: react-native

I want to create a pop-up in react-native using Modal. Modal should be a created in such a way that it can be reused. Please let me know how to do this as I am new to react-native.

Comment: You can use the existing Modal component , can we know how you are planning on reusing ?

Comment: for eg I have an OTP screen where I will use that Modal and I have Customer screen where I can reuse that same Modal but with different Text message and button name.

Comment: You create a wrapper for the modal and pass props as per your requirement

Answer (score 2):

First you will need one state to control when the modal will show.

```
const [show, setShow] = useState(false)
```

And then when the condition was achieved, you will set this state to true and show the modal, I will let one example.

```
<TouchableOpacity 
   onPress={setShow(true)} />
   //some icon
</TouchableOpacity>
```

Now you will use show to control your modal, but first let's create the modal component. You will create one js file and create the modal component inside it.

```
import React from 'react'
import {Modal, View, Text} from 'react-native'

const Modal = ({message, buttonMessage, show, setshow}) => {
return (      
<Modal
     animationType='slide'
     transparent={true}
     visible={show}
     backgroundColor='white'
   >
      //What you want to show inside the modal, Views, Text, whatever, you will construct one 'screen' here
 <View>
     <Text>{message}</Text> //Showing the message
     <Button 
         title={buttonMessage}
         onPress={setShow(false)} //To not show the modal for example 
     />
 </View>
   </Modal>
)}

export default Modal
```

Modal component are receiving at the start message and buttonMessage, so you can pass what you want to the component receive and then use it inside your code, and now when you invoke Modal you will pass message and buttonMessage as props to it use, you will see how. Note that Modal are being exported at the end, so now you can use import it in any screen that you want show it.

Let's suppose that you have one screen and will invoke the Modal component that you create.

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import { View, Text} from 'react-native';
import Modal from 'patch' //Note, patch will be where is the modal file that you create

const ContentCompenent = () => {
   const [show, setShow] = useState(false)
   return (
    <View>
      // Your screen content
      // Your screen content
      
      //Now you will invoke the Modal
      <Modal message={'your message or your variable with the message'} buttomMessage={your message or your variable with the message} show={show} setShow={setShow} />
    </View>
//When you setShow here to true, the modal will appears, and as you are passing setShow as prop to Modal, when you setShow(false) in the modal it will disappears.
```

Comment: I'm used to use Modal from react-native-paper. If you are having troubles with this Modal from react-native, try to use that one from react-native-paper

Comment: Very very helpful, using this I am able to build re-usable custom Alert dialog. Upvote from me... :) Thanks